# Basis of vector space invariant under group action (of symmetric group)

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, permutations

Suppose I have a finite-dimensional real vector space $X$ and a finite group $G$ that acts faithfully on X.

The task is to find a $G$-invariant basis of $X$. This means the set of basis vectors is invariant, not necessarily each basis vector for itself.

I suppose this pertains to representation theory, yet I have no knowledge about the subject and would like to learn about a place where to start. Can you determine whether such a basis exists, and how to compute it?

In fact, $G$ is just a symmetric group of permutations.

PS:
In my application, $X$ is a subspace of the $p$-th symmetric product of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ with the $q$-th alternating product of $x_1,\dots,x_n$,
and it is invariant under permutation of coordinates.

Comment: Please clarify, as such a basis does not necessarily exist. For example, take $G$ to be $c_2$, acting by $\cdot -1$.

Comment: What is $c_2$? However, indeed, such a basis might not exist, but how can this be shown?

Comment: $c_{2}$ is the cyclic group of order 2. As Amitai has shown, invariant bases do not have to exist for arbitrary representations. I'm guessing the representation you care about is a subrepresentation of symmetric and exterior powers of the standard permutation representation of $S_{n}$ on an $n$-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Amitai's argument can actually be extended to the symmetric group as well. $S_{n}$ has a natural one dimensional representation called the sign representation, where an element of $S_{n}$ acts on a basis vector by multiplication by the sign of $S_{n}$. By Amitai's argument, this representation, call it $V$, does not have an invariant basis. But V is the top exterior power of the permutation representation of $S_{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=\{1,-1\}$ act on $V$ by the usual multiplication by scalar. This action is obviously faithful. Let $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ be any basis. $-v_1$ depends linearly on $v_1$, but $-v_1\neq v_1$, hence $-v_1\not\in\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$, and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is not $G$-invariant.